# Camera view in leap motion

Tags: unity-game-engine, leap-motion, oculus

I have a camera view in visualiser in Leap Motion.

[image]

How can I remove this night camera view and see just detection of my hands as a joint number of colored stubs in tutorials?

Answer (score 1):

Press the f key. (This and other key functions are listed on the left of your screen shot there.)